# Are questions asking for app alternatives on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Basically, I found an application that fits my use case but I do not like it for certain reasons. Can I ask for *similar* apps on this site?

Comment: http://alternativeto.net/?platform=android

Comment: I think it should be enlisted as on-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Is there a App for X?" type questions are off-topic. Therefore asking for app alternatives is also off-topic. See the section off-topic on [this help site](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Please note the following topics are expressly off-topic here:
>
> - Recommendations, like "Which phone is better?" or "Can you suggest an app that does X?"

But if you phrase your question like *"How can I do (insert use case here)?"*, then your question is perfectly on-topic.

Android Enthusiasts is not meant as an app recommendation site. There are already a dozen sites for that purpose. We want to solve real problems that are affecting users. The solution is often an app, but not always. That is why especially asking for an app is considered bad practice because it's an apparition of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: That complicates things a little. I am looking for a lightweight way to write and run general purpose C code on my phone. If it were a "how to" question, then (I think) it would still be off-topic (under "Developing/programming for Android").

Comment: No, development questions are off-topic if they are about Android development. But if I understand you correctly you want to develop **under** Android. Why not simply ask "Is there a lightweight way to write and run general purpose C code on Android?". But also  explain your use case. It seems that you want to code  and compile short C snippets for demonstration or learning purpose.

Comment: A person could argue that what runs **on Android** is technically, code **for Android**. Anyways, [question's up](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50839/is-there-a-lightweight-way-to-write-and-run-c-code-on-android). I couldn't think-of/find any appropriate tags.